# jsonencode php doesn't return valid json?

Tags: php, json

I wrote this

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         echo json_encode($obj) . ",";
    }
}
```

and it returned

```
{"tabId":1,"tabName":"Main","uId":"1"},{"tabId":2,"tabName":"Photography","uId":"1"},
```

how to remove the , to make it a valid json?

Comment: You echo a comma and you're surprised that it actually gets echoed?

Answer (score 3):

Each time you go around the loop, you produce a valid JSON text (followed by a comma).

When you join them together (which is the effect of echoing out each time you go around) the result is invalid.

Put the values in an array. Only call `json_encode` at the end.

My PHP is pretty rusty, but I think this will do the job.

```
$data = Array();
if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         $data[] = $obj;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I don't get it, example?